# Flash of unstyled content in Gatsby, for strange/unknown reason. How can I diagnose the issue?

Tags: reactjs, sass, gatsby

I am getting a strange flash of unstyled content on my website. Well, not exactly - most of the styles are loaded, but the icons in my sub-header are huge as the site loads. Then something happens, some style finishes loading, and the icons jump back to the intended size.

I'm using scss (not styled components).

You can see the issue here:

https://playmirage.netlify.app/character-sheet

Here's the code for the page:

https://github.com/raymestalez/mirage-gatsby/blob/master/src/pages/character-sheet.js

Here's the code for the subnav element (the one that has the issue):

https://github.com/raymestalez/mirage-gatsby/blob/master/src/components/CharacterSheet/Subnav.js

The issue happens around `FontAwesomeIcon`'s (the icons load just fine, only the styles don't). What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the computed styles, you'll see that the initial value of the SVG's `height` is `107.571px` so in the first load/render, it takes the default value, once your styles are being rendered. Once loaded, they overwrite the `height` value to `1em` as shown. Afterwards, the `width` is changed to `0.75em`:

```
.svg-inline--fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: inherit;
    height: 1em; // here
    overflow: visible;
    vertical-align: -0.125em;
}

.svg-inline--fa.fa-w-12 {
    width: 0.75em; 
}
```

You'll need to check `@fortawesome/react-fontawesome` [specifications about size](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome#basic) to figure out how to handle it.

Comment: Thank you very much!